# Warning: Lisp directory '~/.emacs.d/site-lisp': No such file or directory

Tags: load-path

I set the environment variable `EMACSLOADPATH` to change Emacs `load-path` this way:

```bash
mkdir ~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/

export EMACSLOADPATH="$(
  emacs      \
  -Q --batch \
  --eval '(princ user-emacs-directory)'
)"/site-lisp/:

# Let's say there is a teeest library:
echo "(provide 'teeest)" \
  > ~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/teeest.el
```

Then ran Emacs

```bash
emacs -Q --batch
```

got stderr:

```
Warning: Lisp directory '~/.emacs.d/site-lisp': No such file or directory
```

Why does Emacs complain?

---

Actually, `require` does know that directory:

```bash
emacs                                \
  -Q --batch                         \
  --eval "(princ (require 'teeest))" \
2> /dev/null ; echo
```

outputs:

```
teeest
```

Comment: Do not quote the RHS of the `export`. That will allow the shell to expand it properly.

Comment: @NickD: Yeah. But sometimes I must quote it (for some strange reason). ||| Posting this question is intended to remind others not to use `~` in `EMACSLOADPATH`. Someone will encounter this problem at some time, and he/she probably does not know the reason why Emacs complains. The existence of this question may help.

Comment: If you need to quote something, then quote that something but leave the tilde alone. E.g. if you have a directory `foo*` under your home directory, do `export EMACSLOADPATH=~/foo"*"`. I fail to see why you think `EMACSLOADPATH` is somehow special or what this has to do with Emacs. The only parsing that Emacs (or any other program) does on a PATH-like environment variable is to split it at colons and construct a list - that's all.

Comment: @NickD: Sometimes you don't know whether there is a tilde in the string, eg `USER_EMACS_SITE_LISP="$(emacs -Q --batch --eval '(princ user-emacs-directory)')/site-lisp/"` (this string may also contain whitespaces). A more realistic case: https://github.com/shynur/.emacs.d/blob/main/etc/use-emacs.bash

Comment: If there is a possibility that there will be a tilde in the output, then make sure that you get rid of it (e.g. use `expand-file-name` on `user-emacs-directory`). That way, it doesn't get a chance to pollute anything downstream. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming.

Comment: On rereading everything, the answer is fine: it's the question that is problematic IMO, because you have "simplified" it too much. The answer to the question as it stands is in my first comment above - there is no need for anything else. But your actual question is different and it explicitly involves the fact that `user-emacs-directory` is a string containing a tilde. That appeared in the answer, but not in the question.

Comment: @NickD: "*On rereading everything, the answer is fine: it's the question that is problematic IMO, because you have "simplified" it too much.*" -- Quite right. Actually, **I just want to remind** others not to put a literal `~` in `EMACSLOADPATH` to represent the HOME directory, by either asking a question or posting an answer. The question is simplified, so I put more information in the answer. Anyway, I'm certain you'll know what I mean 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148131/discussion-between-nickd-and-shynur).

Comment: @NickD: I updated the question and the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>Not sure whether it is an intended behavior</del> - Emacs doesn't recognize `~` in `EMACSLOADPATH`, though `require` does recognize it.

One workaround is to expand the pathname:

```bash
export EMACSLOADPATH="$(
  emacs      \
  -Q --batch \
  --eval '(princ (file-truename user-emacs-directory))'
)"/site-lisp:
```

---

###### Update:

After [@NickD](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/14825)'s patient guidance, I'm inclined to believe that users should not expect Emacs to interpret the shorthand representing the HOME directory in `EMACSLOADPATH`.
As some file systems allow filenames to start with a `~`.